# it is possible in java to run a stream with a branch of foreach, and then keep running the stream with another operations

Tags: java, java-8

I wonder if it is possible to run a stream with a branch of foreach,
and then keep running the stream with another operations..

for example:

this doesn't compile:

(print values and after that keep mapping/flatmapping...)

```
    List<Integer> list = new ArrayList<>();
    list.stream()
            .map(x->new ArrayList<int>( x ).forEach(y-> System.out.print(y)) )
            .map(...)
```

Comment: the short answer is no. but what ultimately do you want to do?

Comment: and this `x->new ArrayList<int>( x ).forEach(y-> System.out.print(y))` makes no sense too; it's probably pseudo-code but still: you would put a single element to a `List`, only to print it, you could have instead do `.peek(System.out::println)`

Comment: It doesn't compile because you can't have an `ArrayList` of primitives.

Answer (score 3):

If you want to print each element in the stream and then perform other processing [peek](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#peek-java.util.function.Consumer-) is an option:

```
list.stream()
        .peek(System.out::println)  // or any other method that consumes Integers
        .map(...)
```

In this case the intermediate action in `peek` will be performed before `map` so each `Integer` will be printed before further processing. If you want to print all numbers before any further processing you need 2 streams.

This part of your code:

```
list.stream()
        .map(x->new ArrayList<int>( x )
```

doesn't seem right. First you are trying to make an `ArrayList` with a primitive `int` instead of `Integer` which isn't allowed in Java. Also `x` here is an `Integer` and a constructor of `ArrayList` that takes an integer uses it to set the capacity (size of underlying array). In that case the `ArrayList` remains empty since nothing has been added and nothing will be printed as the stream is also empty.

Comment: `System.out::println` is probably just an example, the OP wants a different thing here...

Comment: @Eugene he may want this or to print all values in list before any further processing in `map(...)` in which case 2 streams are needed.